# How do I write (test) code that will not be optimized by the compiler/JIT?

Tags: c#, java, .net, optimization, jit

I don't really know much about the internals of compiler and JIT optimizations, but I usually try to use "common sense" to guess what could be optimized and what couldn't. So there I was writing a simple unit test method today:

```
@Test  // [Test] in C#
public void testDefaultConstructor() {
    new MyObject();
}
```

This method is actually all I need. It checks that the default constructor exists and runs without exceptions.

But then I started to think about the effect of compiler/JIT optimizations. Could the compiler/JIT optimize this method by eliminating the `new MyObject();` statement completely? Of course, it would need to determine that the call graph does not have side effects to other objects, which is the typical case for a normal constructor that simply initializes the internal state of the object.

I presume that only the JIT would be allowed to perform such an optimization. This probably means that it's not something I should worry about, because the test method is being performed only once. Are my assumptions correct?

Nevertheless, I'm trying to think about the general subject. When I thought about how to prevent this method from being optimized, I thought I may `assertTrue(new MyObject().toString() != null)`, but this is very dependent on the actual implementation of the `toString()` method, and even then, the JIT can determine that `toString()` method always returns a non-null string (e.g. if actually `Object.toString()` is being called), and thus optimize the whole branch. So this way wouldn't work.

I know that in C# I can use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]`, but this is not what I'm actually looking for. I'm hoping to find a (language-independent) way of making sure that some specific part(s) of my code will actually run as I expect, without the JIT interfering in this process.

Additionally, are there any typical optimization cases I should be aware of when creating my unit tests?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about it.  It's not allowed to ever optimize anything that can make a difference to your system (except for speed).  If you new an object, code gets called, memory gets allocated, it HAS to work.

If you had it protected by an if(false), where false is a final, it could be optimized out of the system completely, then it could detect that the method doesn't do anything and optimize IT out (in theory).

Edit: by the way, it can also be smart enough to determine that this method:

```
newIfTrue(boolean b) {
    if(b)
        new ThisClass();
}
```

will always do nothing if b is false, and eventually figure out that at one point in your code B is always false and compile this routine out of that code completely.

This is where the JIT can do stuff that's virtually impossible in any non-managed language.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why the JIT behaves this way? If an object allocation is useless (as can actually be determined by static analysis in some cases), why wouldn't the JIT just optimize it?

Comment: I can now think of a corner case though, but I think it's rare enough. If the object allocation was done for example to ensure that enough memory is available for some other object(s) (and even making sure no paging will happen), the optimization would invalidate the assumption.

Comment: It is required to leave the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) in a state consistent with having had the program code execute in the JVM in accordance with the Java Memory Model. It is not required to actually execute any specific code or allocate memory in the event that the JIT can prove that the code has no effect on the observable program state.

Comment: Yes, it must act exactly as though it had executed the code so there is no point in worrying about it executing anything differently if it's optomized...

Answer (score 5):

I think if you are worried about it getting optimized away, you may be doing a bit of testing overkill.

In a static language, I tend to think of the compiler as a test. If it passes compilation, that means that certain things are there (like methods). If you don't have another test that exercises your default constructor (which will prove it wont throw exceptions), you may want to think about why you are writing that default constructor in the first place (YAGNI and all that).

I know there are people that don't agree with me, but I feel like this sort of thing is just something that will bloat out your number of tests for no useful reason, even looking at it through TDD goggles.

Comment: I agree with you. When I thought about it (after reading your answer),  there must be other tests that use the default constructor if this test is more important that just being a "compiled" test. Thanks!

Comment: In a language like Java, the compilation and execution environments can vary greatly. A test like this might make sense if the class being constructed is located separately from the test code. Especially interesting would be having a custom class loader load the class on-the-fly from some form of dynamic storage - this code would ensure that the lookup is actually working.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way:

Lets assume that compiler can determine that the call graph doesn't have any side effects(I don't think it is possible, I vaguely remember something about P=NP from my CS courses). It will optimize any method that doesn't have side effects. Since most tests don't have and shouldn't have any side effects then compiler can optimize them all away.

Answer (score 2):

The JIT is only allowed to perform operations that do not affect the guaranteed semantics of the language. Theoretically, it could remove the allocation and call to the `MyObject` constructor *if* it can guarantee that the call has no side effects and can never throw an exception (not counting `OutOfMemoryError`).

In other words, **if the JIT optimizes the call out of your test, then your test would have passed anyway**.

PS: Note that this applies because you are doing *functionality* testing as opposed to *performance* testing. In performance testing, it's important to make sure the JIT does not optimize away the operation you are measuring, else your results become useless.

Comment: Great view on the topic. One addition: When using a performance test for functionality (e.g. such as trying to figure out the cache size of the CPU) we should explicitly add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` to avoid the JIT doing tricks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in C# I could do this:

```
[Test]
public void testDefaultConstructor() {
    GC.KeepAlive(new MyObject());
}
```

AFAIU, the `GC.KeepAlive` method will not be inlined by the JIT, so the code will be guaranteed to work as expected. However, I don't know a similar construct in Java.

Comment: -1: Misleading. This is not the case where `GC.KeepAlive` is required (or even provides any benefit at all).

Answer (score 1):

Every I/O is a side effect, so you can just put

```
Object obj = new MyObject();
System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

and you're fine.

Comment: Yes, this certainly is a way of doing it. But unit tests usually shouldn't have output statements.

Comment: I think that as long as you're not relying on I/O to determine whether the test passed or failed, you're fine.

Comment: -1: Misleading. He is fine without the I/O. This answer makes it appear like unit tests of this form need the I/O in order to guarantee correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it matter? If the compiler/JIT can statically determine no asserts are going to be hit (which could cause side effects), then you're fine.

Comment: It also needs to verify that the constructor exists, does not affect static program state, and cannot throw an exception implicitly required by the JVM such as a `NullPointerException`.